# How to plot average value lines and not every single value in Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, line, average

First of all; sorry if what I am writing here is not up to stackoverflow standards, I am trying my best.

I have a `dataframe` with around 18k rows and 89 columns with information about football players.

For example I need to plot a line graph to visualize the connection between age and overall rating of a player.

But when I plot a line for that with:

```
fig = px.line(df, x="Age", y="Overall")
fig.show()
```

This is the result:

[Bad Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hRBN.png)

This is obviously not a good visualization.

I want to plot the average rating for every age, so its a single line which shows the connection between age and overall rating. Is there an easy function for plotting or do I have to create the right data myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you might want to do here is `groupby()` on "age" and then average on "overall" to create a final dataframe before plugging into that plotting function.

Roughly,

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "age": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "overall": [50, 100, 1, 1, 600, 700],
    # clarifies how to select the correct column to average
    "irrelevant": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df = df.groupby('age')['overall'].mean()
new_df

# age
# 1     75.0
# 2      1.0
# 3    650.0
# Name: overall, dtype: float64
```

Alternatively, you can use a scatter plot if you're comfortable having the individual points show the trend instead. Sometimes scatter plots are useful for this situation since a line of averages might have very different samples sizes at each point on the x axis, so you can *lose* information by making a line.